Is there any way I can fix this serializer validation error?
I'm trying to create an Order in Django with an optional promo_code, but I'm getting a validation error:
{
    "promo_code": {
        "code": [
            "This field may not be blank."
        ]
    }
}

Here are my models:
class PromoCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    promo_code = models.ForeignKey(
        PromoCode, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )

In my OrderSerializer, I define promo_code to allow null and set required=False:
from rest_framework import serializers

class PromoCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PromoCode
        fields = ['code']

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    promo_code = PromoCodeSerializer(allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['promo_code']


test_payload = {
            "items": [{"id": "bb6ccdd4-3218-4794-a16a-9327cdfec56f"}],
            "order_date": "2024-11-15",
            "promo_code": {
                "code": ""
            },
            "shipping_info": {
                "shipping_address": "pursitie 7 F"
            },
            "first_name": "Ebenezer",
            "last_name": "Ofori-Mensah",
            "email": "oforimensahebenezer07@gmail.com"
        }

The issue is that when trying to create an order without providing a promo_code (like test_payload), I still get the validation error for promo_code saying:

"This field may not be blank." .

I expected promo_code to be optional.

you can override the def create(self, validated_date) function to make it optional

What if you use promo_code: null,?

Can you also specify how you test the serializer?

Following @sudip-parajuli's suggestions I modified my PromoCode serializer as below:
class PromoCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PromoCode

I also overrode the validate method of the OrderSerializer to remove promo_code data when the code value is empty:
def validate(self, data: dict):
    promo_code_data: dict = data.get("promo_code", None)
    if promo_code_data and promo_code_data.get("code"):
        return data
    else:
        data.pop("promo_code", None)
        return data

Solved my problem.

Thi is an example of how to override the def create(self, validated_data) under your OrderSerializer class.
def create(self, validated_data):
    promo_code_data = validated_data.pop('promo_code', None) 
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
    if promo_code_data:
        promo_code, created = PromoCode.objects.get_or_create(**promo_code_data)
        order.promo_code = promo_code 
        order.save()
        return order


The issue is since you're passing an empty string ("") for the code field in the promo_code dictionary of the payload. Even though you've marked the
promo_code field as optional in your OrderSerializer, this does not apply to the nested PromoCodeSerializer. The code field in PromoCodeSerializer is still required and cannot be blank. Alternatively what you can do is you can set allow_blank values instead of allow_null=True
class PromoCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  code = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)  

You have another option too you can remove the promo_code field by making some utility function to clean things and then send the payload incase of empty promo_code, if you don't want to make change to the serializers.
test_payload = {
    "items": [{"id": "bb6ccdd4-3218-4794-a16a-9327cdfec56f"}],
    "order_date": "2024-11-15",
    "shipping_info": {
        "shipping_address": "pursitie 7 F"
    },
    "first_name": "Ebenezer",
    "last_name": "Ofori-Mensah",
    "email": "oforimensahebenezer07@gmail.com"
}


Thank you @sudip-parajuli. after setting allow_blank=True I provided an override of the validate method to exclude promo_code from the payload if the code value in the promo_code data is empty. Combining both of your suggestions worked for me. Thank you.

It makes no sense to pass an empty string as code to use this as None for the promo_code.
If there is no promo code, you pass it as null:
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "bb6ccdd4-3218-4794-a16a-9327cdfec56f"
    }
  ],
  "order_date": "2024-11-15",
  "promo_code": null,
  "shipping_info": {
    "shipping_address": "pursitie 7 F"
  },
  "first_name": "Ebenezer",
  "last_name": "Ofori-Mensah",
  "email": "oforimensahebenezer07@gmail.com"
}
or you do not specify it at all:
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "bb6ccdd4-3218-4794-a16a-9327cdfec56f"
    }
  ],
  "order_date": "2024-11-15",
  "shipping_info": {
    "shipping_address": "pursitie 7 F"
  },
  "first_name": "Ebenezer",
  "last_name": "Ofori-Mensah",
  "email": "oforimensahebenezer07@gmail.com"
}
If you specify promo_code then that means there is a related PromoCode object. By seeing this as some sort of "none value", you make multiple representations for null, which typically only will make it more complicated.
